# Forking CodeIgniter on github

Tags: codeigniter, github, fork

I'd like to fork the CodeIgniter repo on github and make some changes to it for my personal use, which I haven't done yet, but I will once the following question is answered :)

If the CodeIgniter repo has had some changes done to it (for example, they fixed a security issue) **after** I forked it. How can I merge their latest changes with my forked version?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter for the less informed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just pull into your repo.  E.g.:

```
git pull codeIgniterUrl remoteBranchName
```

Of course, you may have to merge, in which case [git mergetool](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-mergetool) and/or another tool may be helpful.

Comment: Yes, although the merging may be tricky, mainly if there are a lot of changes that conflict with your own.